# Bookdown pdf output only shows "placeholder"

Tags: r, bookdown

I am writing my thesis in bookdown and notice that all the content of the chapter will not display if I use these codes

````
# Results {#result}

In many scenarios, we are interested in the magnitude of some set of numbers.

```{r lpo, echo = FALSE, fig.cap="LPO"}
barplot(1:10)
```

I have a custom block that has within it an enumerated list.
````

[image: Text]

But when I delete the paragraph before the code chunk of figure, it works normally.

````
# Results {#result}

```{r lpo, echo = FALSE, fig.cap="LPO"}
barplot(1:10)
```

I have a custom block that has within it an enumerated list.
````

[image: Text]

Here is my index file

```
--- 
title: ""
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
      before_body: before_body.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc_bib: TRUE
bibliography: ["ref0.bib", "ref1.bib"]
biblio-style: apa
biblio-title: References, heading=bibintoc
link-citations: yes
indent: true
description: "thesis"
mainfont: Times New Roman
papersize: a4
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
toc-depth: 1
secnumdepth: 1
lof: True
lot: True
geometry: "left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
---
```

I experienced this problem before in previous chapter. Deleting some empty lines at the end of .Rmd seems to fix that. I guess it is related to the floating of figures and tables.

Update: the merged RMd file turned all the code chunks into "Placeholder".

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: @MKR Thank you. I added the code, not sure if it is enough. I notice that when all rmd file are merged and knitted, code chunks are not evaluated.

Comment: "Placeholder" appears when you preview a single chapter (presumably you clicked the Knit button): https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/preview-a-chapter.html You should see the full content if you build the whole book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/get-started.html (or if you prefer the command line: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/build-the-book.html)